# Подсчёт значений в столбце Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Задача:

посчитать кол-во слов "*Яблоко*" в столбце *C*. Всего строк, предположим, 10000. То есть начинаем проверку с *C2* до *С10001*.

Понимаю, что в коде ошибка. Во-первых, он не считает именно в столбце *C*. Во-вторых, ну чёт с ним не так... Устал, помогите. Работа с *excel*-файлом, конечно.

```
Sub makros()
    Dim role As String
    Dim k As Integer
role = "Яблоко"
k = 0
For i = 2 To 10001
    If role = True Then
    k = k + 1
    End If
Next i
Cells(1, 1) = k
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

*role* не может быть *True*, это строковая переменная (не *Boolean*)

Проверять нужно совпадение значения ячейки *Cells(i, 3)* с заданным текстом. В адресе ячейки i - строка, тройка указывает на столбец *C*

```
Sub makros()
Dim role As String
Dim i As Long, k As Long
    role = "Яблоко"

    For i = 2 To 100001
        If Cells(i, 3).Value = role Then k = k + 1
    Next i

    Cells(1, 1).Value = k
End Sub
```

Оператор *If* можно писать без закрытия, если запись в одной строке. Аналогичная полная запись:

```
If Cells(i, 3) = role Then
    k = k + 1
End If
```

Вместо всего написанного можно применить функцию листа:

```
Sub makros2()
    Cells(1, 1) = Application.CountIf(Range("C2:C10001"), "Яблоко")
End Sub
```

Или посчитать то же самое без применения *VBA*

```
=СЧЕТЕСЛИ(C:C;"Яблоко")
```